# One of my computers won’t boot up from after a brief power outage?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

After a brief power outage, one of my computers that was on at the time refuses to boot. It never gets past the BIOS splash screen and then shows the "please insert bootable device…" message.

After trying to boot with a Windows 10 USB and Live Ubuntu desktop, I couldn't see the `C:` drive using File Explorer, but I could see the `D:` drive.

I tried to connect the systems’s boot SSD to another PC using a SATA to USB adapter. Windows 10 did recognize it in the device manager but I still couldn't access it.

Looking at the SSD in the Device Manager I see this. What does this mean regarding the state of SSD? Is there any way I can recover the data, and what should I search for?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a corrupt device driver, due to the "device not migrated error."

Open an Administrative command prompt and run `sfc /scannow`

Hopefully that will fix the issue.

Then try reconnecting the drive.

Comment: I can't, it does not even recognize the SSD . And I have the same SSD model in the other PC, (the one that I connected the problematic SSD to) that does work. So I don't think it's a driver error.